# Cannot edit search bar width and x y coordinate in `UITableViewController`

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I am useing the swreveal to do the slide menu which i want to add search bar in it. However, the search bar has been covered by the parent view.

[image]

```
    slide_areaWidth = self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealWidth
    searchBar =  UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(300, 0, 60, 64))
    var searchDisplayController: UISearchDisplayController = UISearchDisplayController()
    searchDisplayController = UISearchDisplayController(searchBar: searchBar, contentsController: self)
    //searchDisplayController.delegate = self
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView!.frame = CGRectMake(300, 0, 60, 64);
```

Comment: in here add the frame for search is using **window position** + x, else use delegate method of `SWLRevel`  **- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController didMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position**

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand the window position + x. Do you mean UIScreen? Thank you very much

Comment: i found the solution which is edit the `self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealOverdraw ` to 0. thank you very much for your helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way that can solve this issue which can be find in SWRevealViewController.m

Swift:
`self.revealViewController().rightViewRevealOverdraw = 0`